# Compute gradients for unknown number of factor

Tags: octave

Is there a better way to write this? More particularly, is there a way to remove the loop and calculate `grad` directly without iterating?

```
for j = 1:size(theta)
    grad(j) = 1 / m * sum((h - y) .* X(:, j));
endfor
```

`h` and `y` are both vectors, `X` is a matrix with an arbitrary number of rows and the same number of columns as `theta`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be pretty optimized.

The only other way; this code can be written; is initializing grad to a zeros matrix and then using the vectorized computation for carrying out the necessary Grad. descent optimization algorithm.